# Dispatching action on Route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have a smart `User` component that renders user information from `Redux` state.

Here is a route I defined:

```
<Route path="/users/:id" component={User}/>
```

Whenever I click on a specific user, route changes and it forces component to update. However when route changes I wish to dispatch a `Redux` action to fetch user details by `:id` from an external API.

What is the correct approach of fetching new set of data for `User` component after changing `Route` path?

I have tried to dispatch `Redux` action on `componentWillReceiveProps()` but this causes infinite loop since the action causes component to update again... repeat.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in `componentWillReceiveProps` but there you can provide a condition on present and nextProps like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if(this.props.params.id !== nextProps.params.id) {
        //...action here 
    }
}
```

Comment: i also use the same way

Comment: @yussan This is probably the right and best way to do it

Comment: I would also consider taking a discussion of bad thinking in terms of design. Maybe my design is not right? I am looking at the solution here but I think it is a bit hacky and error prone. A single condition is just a beginning... in the long run the maintainability will reduce if I, you anyone has to add and read through all if conditions.